# covert javascript code to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to convert some javascript code into jQuery. Can any one help me the better way. Here is my code

```
var temp = jQuery(element.nodeName);
temp.innerHTML = "test";
temp = element.appendChild(temp);
var lineHeight = temp.clientHeight;
element.removeChild(temp);
return lineHeight;
```

Comment: Hello madhu, please use proper formatting if you post code, that makes it easier for us to read.

Comment: this is more suited for a code review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is still pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve from your test code, i see a mix of plain js and jquery calls that will never work.

Comment: @Zathrus do you know for sure CodeReview.SE are open towards rewriting requests? (I honestly don't know)

Comment: @Pekka웃 not for sure, but I know for sure that SO is not the place to be for this one... and it's a review case in my view for sure

Comment: @Pekka웃 Just now I too found out. It is awesome! :)

Comment: @Zathrus The smaller SE sites get lots of crap from SO - ie. questions they don't really want, and that should have just been closed on SO instead of sent to them. I'd be careful with site recommendations, so as not to draw the wrath of another SE community :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thank you, I wasn't aware of the situation... will be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... You should have searched anyway...

```
var temp = jQuery(element.nodeName);
temp.html("test");
temp = element.append(temp);
var lineHeight = temp.css("line-height");
element.find(temp).remove();
return lineHeight;
```